# Create dynamic cross table in Angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to create a dynamic table in Angular material where in lines I have users and in columns I have hobbies, the data in the table are checkboxs where the user can link a uer to one or several hobbies and when finish I must send the choices to the server in http. Have you any idea how I can do that

[image]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the buttons in the hobbies column with functions to replace true and false, you can check my result

this for function in javascript:

```
function myFunction(str) {
 if (document.getElementById(str).innerHTML == "true") {
  document.getElementById(str).innerHTML = "false"
 } else document.getElementById(str).innerHTML = "true"
}
```

and this for html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Foot</th>
    <th>Running</th>
    <th>Swimming</th>
    <th>Baseball</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id_user1</td>
    <td id="foot1" onclick="myFunction('foot1')">true</td>
    <td id="running1" onclick="myFunction('running1')">false</td>
    <td id="swim1" onclick="myFunction('swim1')">false</td>
    <td id="baseball1" onclick="myFunction('baseball1')">false</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id_user2</td>
    <td id="foot2" onclick="myFunction('foot2')">false</td>
    <td id="running2" onclick="myFunction('running2')">false</td>
    <td id="swim2" onclick="myFunction('swim2')">false</td>
    <td id="baseball2" onclick="myFunction('baseball2')">true</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id_user3</td>
    <td id="foot3" onclick="myFunction('foot3')">true</td>
    <td id="running3" onclick="myFunction('running3')">false</td>
    <td id="swim3" onclick="myFunction('swim3')">false</td>
    <td id="baseball3" onclick="myFunction('baseball3')">false</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>id_user4</td>
    <td id="foot4" onclick="myFunction('foot4')">false</td>
    <td id="running4" onclick="myFunction('running4')">false</td>
    <td id="swim4" onclick="myFunction('swim4')">true</td>
    <td id="baseball4" onclick="myFunction('baseball4')">true</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I think this can work in javascript, maybe just change it to typescript in your case if you want, hopefully can help